# Issues changing the background colour of the currently selected item in a ListView - Nativescript/Angular2

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a Nativescript/Angular2 app where I display a list of active stock takes in a ListView.  I am trying to change the background color lf the current selected stock take item in the ListView to show the currently selected StockTake.  I add the css class to the StackLayout inside the ng-template but for some reason the css isn't applied when I tap on a item.  Any idea what could be going wrong here/how I can fix this?  I don't get any errors so i'm completely lost as to what the issue might be here...

```
    my ListView xml code:

    <ListView [items]="activeStockTakes" class="list-group">
                        <ng-template let-activeStockTake="item" let-i="index">
                            <StackLayout [class.highlight]="item.isSelected" (tap)="selectActiveStockTake(item, index)">
                                <Label class="list-group-item" [text]="activeStockTake.UserCode + ' - ' + activeStockTake.Comment"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ng-template>
                    </ListView>


    my css code:

    .highlight {
        background-color: red !important;
        border-radius: 3;
    }

    my selectActiveStockTake event:

selectActiveStockTake(item, index) {
    //console.log(args.index);
    this.selectedActiveStockTake = this.activeStockTakes[index];
    this.selectedActiveStockTake.isSelected = true;
    console.log(this.selectedActiveStockTake.UserCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<ListView [items]="activeStockTakes" class="list-group">
    <ng-template let-activeStockTake="item" let-i="index">
        <StackLayout [class.highlight]="item.isSelected" (tap)="selectActiveStockTake(item, i)">
            <Label class="list-group-item" [text]="activeStockTake.UserCode + ' - ' + activeStockTake.Comment"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

and then:

```
selectActiveStockTake(item, i) {
  item.isSelected = !item.isSelected;
}
```

This is a much cleaner solution and should work perfectly.

Comment: The only issue with that is that I need the index which is obtained from the event to post to the backend at a later stage.  Also my current selectedActiveStockTakeItem model doesn't have a isSelected field...

Comment: @user2094257 You can access the index via `let-i="index"` on the `ng-template`. And `isSelected` was just an example. You can use `item['isSelected']` too to prevent lint errors.

Comment: Just to confirm then I would pass index to the selectActiveStockTakeItem function as well? e.g. selectActiveStocktake(item, index)?

Comment: I updated my code/question to your solution...  I now get a runtime error when I navigate to the stocktake page.  I get the activeStockTakes in ngOninit so it's displayed when the view loads.  I added a isSelected field to the model:  public isSelected ? : boolean;  I added the ? as this property isn't returned by the backend initially when the view loads.

Comment: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method getView failed

[object Object]
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js, line: 12764, column: 20