# how to change background color of selected item in listview

Tags: nativescript

cannot able to change the background color of the selected item in listview.

i tried to understand this.but the solution was in angular where i'm not getting how to use that in javascript.

[Issues changing the background colour of the currently selected item in a ListView - Nativescript/Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43538609/issues-changing-the-background-colour-of-the-currently-selected-item-in-a-listview)

```
onItemTap: function (args) {
      console.log('Item with index: ' + args.index + ' tapped');
      args.object.backgroundColor = "#3489db";
    },
```

here i can change background of complete listview.

playground sample.
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=KZeq3j

i want only the selected item to get its background to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the playground for you [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=KZeq3j&v=4). args.object gives you the listview itself.

```
onItemTap: function (args) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.countries.length; i++) {
        this.countries[i].bgColor = "#FFFFFF";
      }
      console.log(this.countries[args.index])
      this.countries[args.index].bgColor = "#3489db";
      args.object.refresh();
    },
```